# Comparing a variable to a character in Lisp

Tags: comparison, character, lisp, common-lisp, clisp

I am new in lisp programming and  I am trying to compare a variable let's say op to the characters  +,-,*,/. But in every way I write the correct result doesn't show up. How could I rewrite the following code:

```
(defun evaluate(op o1 o2)
  (cond
    ( (string= op `+) (+ o1 o2))
    ( (string= op `-) (- o1 o2))
    ( (string= op `*) (* o1 o2))
    ( (string= op `/) (/ o1 o2))
  )
)
```

the input is:

```
(print (calculate `(- * + 4 3 2 5)))
```

So I get in my function the operator characters. Don't mind the numbers.
To be sure here is the calculate function.

```
(defun calculate (l)
  (if (and (numberp (car l)) (not (null l)) )
      (car l)
    ( evaluate (car l) (calculate (cdr l) ) 
    (calculate (cdr l) ) )
  )
)
```

Comment: You're calling `evaluate` with just two arguments. It requires 3 arguments.

Comment: `evaluate` is written correctly, the problem is in `calculate`.

Comment: However, you shouldn't use `string=`, use `eql`. None of your input is strings, they're symbols and numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way `calculate` is written, this evaluates `(- (* (+ 4 4) (+ 4 4)) (* (+ 4 4) (+ 4 4)))`, which is 0.  I don't know what you expect, but let's take a look at tracing (`SO>` is the repl prompt):

```
SO> (trace evaluate calculate)
(EVALUATE CALCULATE)
SO> (calculate '(- * + 4 3 2 5))
  0: (SO::CALCULATE (- * + 4 3 2 5))
    1: (SO::CALCULATE (* + 4 3 2 5))
      2: (SO::CALCULATE (+ 4 3 2 5))
        3: (SO::CALCULATE (4 3 2 5))
        3: CALCULATE returned 4
        3: (SO::CALCULATE (4 3 2 5))
        3: CALCULATE returned 4
        3: (SO::EVALUATE + 4 4)
        3: EVALUATE returned 8
      2: CALCULATE returned 8
      2: (SO::CALCULATE (+ 4 3 2 5))
        3: (SO::CALCULATE (4 3 2 5))
        3: CALCULATE returned 4
        3: (SO::CALCULATE (4 3 2 5))
        3: CALCULATE returned 4
        3: (SO::EVALUATE + 4 4)
        3: EVALUATE returned 8
      2: CALCULATE returned 8
      2: (SO::EVALUATE * 8 8)
      2: EVALUATE returned 64
    1: CALCULATE returned 64
    1: (SO::CALCULATE (* + 4 3 2 5))
      2: (SO::CALCULATE (+ 4 3 2 5))
        3: (SO::CALCULATE (4 3 2 5))
        3: CALCULATE returned 4
        3: (SO::CALCULATE (4 3 2 5))
        3: CALCULATE returned 4
        3: (SO::EVALUATE + 4 4)
        3: EVALUATE returned 8
      2: CALCULATE returned 8
      2: (SO::CALCULATE (+ 4 3 2 5))
        3: (SO::CALCULATE (4 3 2 5))
        3: CALCULATE returned 4
        3: (SO::CALCULATE (4 3 2 5))
        3: CALCULATE returned 4
        3: (SO::EVALUATE + 4 4)
        3: EVALUATE returned 8
      2: CALCULATE returned 8
      2: (SO::EVALUATE * 8 8)
      2: EVALUATE returned 64
    1: CALCULATE returned 64
    1: (SO::EVALUATE - 64 64)
    1: EVALUATE returned 0
  0: CALCULATE returned 0
0
```

That last 0 is the result.  Of the numbers, only the first one is ever touched, and I guess you meant to use the others too.

It should be helpful to point out that the two calls to `(calculate (cdr l))` inside of `calculate` will always produce the same result.

Side notes:

- use standard formatting (see e. g. http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/syntax-and-semantics.html#formatting-lisp-code)
- use the apostrophe `'`, not the backtick.  The latter has different uses.
- understand the difference between symbols and strings

Comment: Ok, thanks for the tracking. I expect it to calculate the prefix notation arithmetic expression given in the list l. And I hoped that the  list gets passed by reference and all the cdr's done firstly will be seen in the second call.